# Lisp %var naming convention

Tags: common-lisp, naming-conventions

In the https://www.cliki.net/Naming+conventions page i read

> low-level, fast, dangerous function, or Lisp system specific implementation of foo

Can someone translate this into again with perhaps an example of those contexts?

Answer (score 8):

Take this function:

```
(defun add (x y)
  (+ x y))
```

which does general addition. It supports integers, floats, complex numbers and ratios as arguments - all the numeric types defined in Lisp.

However if you have:

```
(defun add (x y)
  (declare (fixnum x y) (optimize speed (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (the fixnum (+ x y)))
```

this tells the compiler to optimize the function for `fixnum` values that fit in an assembly register. When you use an implementation that compiles down to assembly this results in very efficient code, as you can check with `(disassemble (compile 'add))`. For example in Allegro CL:

```
cl-user(10): (disassemble 'add)
;; disassembly of #<Function add>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
;; formals: x y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

;; code start: #x10008ae4740:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   0: 48 01 f7       addq       rdi,rsi
   3: f8             clc
   4: 4c 8b 74 24 10 movq       r14,[rsp+16]
   9: c3             ret
```

However this faster code comes at the cost of not having *any* error checking: the code *assumes* you pass in 2 `fixnum` arguments, no more or less, and also you promise that the result will not overflow the `fixnum` range - so not e.g. `(add most-positive-fixnum most-positive-fixnum)`.

If you break this promise by passing floats like `(add 3.4 1.2)` or only arg `(add 3)` you are asking for big trouble - this might corrupt data structures or even exit the Lisp.

The second function could be called `%add-2-fixnums` to signal it's special, not intended for general use but instead specialized for certain arguments, and callers need to be very careful.

Answer (score 4):

The function without `%` is the general interface into some functionality and may even check its arguments. It then calls a low-level implementation.

The same function with the prefix `%` then might implement the functionality efficiently, even in a platform specific way.

If this function then uses a macro for even more specific low-level code generation, one might prefix the macro with `%%`.

these other cases can be seen, too:

- type specific functions
- inlined functions
- implementation specific functions
- very low-level code working near the Lisp implementation level
- Lisp assembly functions (functions written in inline assembler)

Example: If one checks for example the source code of Clozure Common Lisp, there is a lot of use of the `%` naming conventions.